# Subquery returned more than 1 value in C# foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am getting the above error in a foreach statement in some C# code that I have "inherited" it essentially reads csv files and makes changes in a database depending on the info in the csv.

The code is as below:

```
 using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
        {
            foreach (var notification in despatches)
            {
                var componentCheck = ctx.DespatchLineComponentCheck(notification.ProductCode).ToList();
```

The despatches, gets a list of custom DespatchLines type, which are essentially a model.

As far as I can tell the code calls a stored procedure that in turn calls a view.

The stored procedure and the view execute no problems which makes me think that it's the C# code, but I am a little unsure.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a SQL error to me. Can you debug and see what is being passed to the stored proc at the point it fails?

Comment: Agree with @Leonidas199x "Subquery returned more than one value" is a common SQL error. What's the code for your view? Some sample data would help if you can include it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments from @Leonidas199x and @Jacob H. In the end it was an SQL error, with a stored procedure calling on a table that returned multiple results when it should have only given one.

A user here had put data in that wasn't unique and had caused the error.

Thanks for the help!